# Typescript: Compare two different Array of objects having a common key and get common objects from source array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to compare if an item exists in another array by checking a common property value. For the below code it is throwing the below error:

**TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'U[K]' and 'T[K]' have no overlap.**

```
 const sourceArray = [{requestId: "1", name: "henry"},{requestId: "2", name: "bob"}] 
 const arrayListToCompareWith = [{requestId: "1", age: 30}, {requestId: "9", age: 40}]
 const commonItems = getItemsInSourceArrayWhichArePresentInArrayToBeComparedWith(sourceArray,arrayListToCompareWith, "requestId" )
 
 function getItemsInSourceArrayWhichArePresentInArrayToBeComparedWith<
    T,
    U,
    K extends keyof T & keyof U,
  >(
    sourceArray: T[],
    arrayListToCompareWith: U[],
    comparisonKey: K, // "requestId"
  ) {
    const itemsInSourceArrayWhichAreNotPresentInArrayToBeComparedWith: T[] =
      sourceArray.filter((sourceArrayItem: T): boolean => {
        const { [comparisonKey]: sourceArrayItemComparisonKeyValue } = sourceArrayItem; sourceArrayItemComparisonKeyValue
        const itemExistsInTheArrayWeAreComparingWith: boolean =
          arrayListToCompareWith.some((itemToCompareWith: U): boolean => {
            const comparisonValueInItemToCompareWith = itemToCompareWith[comparisonKey]; // U[K]
            const comparisonValueInSource = sourceArrayItemComparisonKeyValue; //T[K]
            // TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'U[K]' and 'T[K]' have no overlap.
            const check = comparisonValueInItemToCompareWith === comparisonValueInSource;
            return check;
          });
        return itemExistsInTheArrayWeAreComparingWith;
      });
    return itemsInSourceArrayWhichArePresentInArrayToBeComparedWith;
  }
```

Below is the TS playground link for the above code problem:

[TS Playground link to run the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQYw9gdgzgLsVgK4CcQFMCCzkEMCewAvMANoDeyaAjomrAJIAmAXMAEQCMbANMBDgFs0rNgAs0EZHjYBfbhWq0GLdgCYefQcPYAjMDtkBdYAFgAUKEixgObPgAyAS1gAVMAGEwAgA620AdUcYUSJSBRo6GCYRLl4cAHNtAGYABjlgcKUolTYATg0E7QAWNMNzS2g4cAEBSHoYNAEoUMSohqb6CABlJFRMOzx-UUcQUSw0AAVKKAkoiCxcPDcAITRPHz9GQOCACgQUdAX8bltFp1cPL19KbdFeNkoI5TZgAEpy8oAzRAgQGEdIMBWvVGlBOj0Dv1FkMRmNKFM6LNOkclmBVutrmgtkFRAAecrAQkubgEwkAVRJFkJwAA0sA0AAPBoQRjNADWaDwYE+wBcwAAZMAOVyeRSCQA+Hak+C9Q4DVguEiGSnUmwDc4wNwYvy3VhkpUq6nVa7OSA0zmsGm8AD01vYjyyTDYBNeGWl4EqwCCoPBsqh+Bho3GCJmEDmKJWayum11vKVRGlhP2fRRADpPo4ADYNZA7PZ+lEggQK16sPRgTNoHAQIjit1U1WEj3WMikY22U0Qc14QysZNyxZF7XITvdgBqOEztGAMlC-f9eCLAG4ZZDC+1h6POROp2hE0arHBvQIAKIM5wwMEQFziFH+fpRjYjiDxWPlyvVhMNxuE04OC9atGNw4qmCBCHmx6AU+AQ4nqpbAO+VY1oQdZkPuP7NlUQGdjutCdEWUGYrcoSQZc0G3CQ7YjggXacoYK62sA+o0mU34-k2h6WE+OGTnh3R+nOBYDEO2E0eOvFoAx1qKix6GNoxLhdKoSQAGwAOwKsMzQeowQQAjWADuWaZjYmYGfgzSUDAKA1gA5J8k4zLZ8COL8aDAME7kwHg3h0MAtnMYYznVow-kyUFwCiDgABu7kQGAwBgLFyCZjg3ipnJqqYaA4ggGyoRUTxu74e0hE6jiRCEMQhU0bhaC+pCS6ZdSVk2TlaB5U1bGNjIrxdexwCtcgNbHmeF5XjeC73uMm4vrc-U9X10pDSN7RXhCKYDIGcKTNMSLzAMkbDli80EjI5jmEAA)

Comment: Are these your real function and variable names? Why are they miles long?

Comment: Thinking it will help in readability, and make others understand what I am trying to convey.

Comment: Shorter names make for more readable code, all else being equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't tell Typescript that there is any relationship between `T` and `U`, in particular you didn't say that they must have the same value type for the property `K`.

Actually there is no need for your second type parameter `U` - all we need to say is that the second array contains objects which have a key `K` with the same value type as `T` does. This can be more simply written as `Pick<T, K>`.

```
function filterByKey<T, K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], keysToKeep: Pick<T, K>[], key: K) {
  return arr.filter(
    item => keysToKeep.some(
      otherItem => item[key] === otherItem[key]
    )
  );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgIQJ4DSGeAPACoA0iBiGAHpmACYDOiA1sXMImQHwAKAIZYsALl4BtALpVOeFmThEMABwkAFGBHbkqBPjLnEJBAJSIA3gFgAUIkRYMUEFiQisAOhTpsAuw4OMJgAtogAvHwcxIrKGGqeLHAhGP72gQ5wUAAW2ACSoRFRwRghkvLSEeHhiFm5WAWl5cTSAYFmbWYA3HYAvnZ2EAgsUIgeEYiSlk4AjiAYI3lMEgBEAIwrVGBCKau5YFh4K70U0xhzC1BLqwBMm4jbu4grAEZwL8fSPbZDYCPRCiUKlUEyms3mi2Wzw2VCEAHMMBIAMwABhOVnBl2uzwAnPd4YjEAAWNFfQbDUZOFggdATHyYXCEYjCUTGQFxNRUFaYyErbp2IA)

Comment: I am not sure how typescript playground is not throwing an error because when you pass `keysToKeep` array which has an `age` property  as a mandatory parameter. But with Pick<T,K> you will get the type which does not have `age`. I clearly demonstrated the issue in the below playground link.
TO Summarize:
1.With Pick<T,K> keysToKeep variable will have type {requestId: string, name: string}.

2. But `keysToKeep` has type `KeysToKeep` with `age` as a mandatory params.

3. Not sure why TS playground is not throwing an error

Correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: The Typescript Playground link in my answer does not show an error, because there is no error. The array `keysToKeep` is assignable to the type `Pick<T, K>[]` because it is an array whose members are assignable to the type `Pick<T, K>`. They are assignable to the type `Pick<T, K>` because they have all the properties required in order to be assignable to that type; the fact that they have extra properties is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you. I had to understand typescript soundness to understand your solution on why Pick<T,K> is working and not throwing an error.
Soundness link : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness 
Will this solution work if ** strictFunctionTypes** is enabled?

Comment: The Playground link has strict mode enabled, so yes, it works with `strictFunctionTypes` and all the other strict config settings. (`strictFunctionTypes` in particular has literally no effect here.) This isn't unsound behaviour, it's just structural subtyping.

Comment: thank you for your help.